# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier with cells of different size

Tags: ios, uitableview

STEP 1 - this is working fine

I have UITableView that loads custom UITableViewCells

STEP 2 - this is kinda works

I change the UITableViewCell height so that all the data contained in the cell within a UITextView is visible

I manage to get the UItextView data and resize it by using the following code:

```
UITextView *dummy = [[UITextView alloc] init];
dummy.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
dummy.text = cell.textView.text;

CGSize newSize = [dummy sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(270.0f, 500.0f)];

//get the textView frame and change it's size
CGRect newFrame = cell.textView.frame;
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(270.0f, fmaxf(newSize.height, 60));
cell.textView.frame = newFrame;

//resize the cell view I add +95 because my cell has borders and other stuff...
CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, newFrame.size.height+95);
cell.cellView.frame = cellFrame;
```

I then manage to set the UITableViewCell height using the delegate function heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Now when I run the code and scroll up and down the table cells the behavious isn't always as expected... i.e the cell size isn't always the right size, but if I scroll up and down it sometimes loads up the right size again. 
I am thinking that perhaps the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is the issue

```
cellIdentifier = @"tableCell";
ctTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Since I am recycling cells of different size with the same identifier...

Can anybody give me some guidelines on how best to solve this issue?

Thanks!!!

[image: Screenshot1 of when the cell is first loaded]

[image: screenshot 2 after scrolling notice how the top cell is rectified]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by adding UITextView dynamically inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method. assumptions(data array contains the content to be displayed inside cell)
// Defines

```
#define CELL_TEXTVIEW_WIDTH = 320        
#define CELL_TEXTVIEW_HEIGHT = 9999  
#define PADDING = 5

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tableCell";

ctTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil){

cell =  [[tableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}

 NSString *_data = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

CGSize _data_contentsize  = [_data sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CELL_TEXTVIEW_WIDTH, CELL_TEXTVIEW_HEIGHT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakModeWordWrap];

UITextView *dummy=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 290, _data_contentsize +(PADDING * 2))];

// add Font and text color for your textview here

[cell.contentView addSubview:dummy];

return cell;

}
```

After this calculate the height of the cell under heightForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: you can add the textView styles in your ctTableViewCell class awakeFromNib Method

Comment: forgot to add the view dummy to the cell content view, will update my answer

Comment: Ok guys here is the deal - I tried the above solution and it worked, then I was surprised that doing something dynamically would work and not through the XIB so I reverted back to my solution by recreating a new UITextView and this time it worked. I think this is a xcode or iOS bug... sometimes you just don't understand what is going on. Also in this guest to find a solution I learn't a neat trick that can help debug those I don't get it behaviours when stuff works on phone but not on simulator etc... clean the project with cmd + shift + k

Answer (score 0):

have you implemented following method ?

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

you should set height for each row , if they are different from each other